# Twilio Chat - Javascript SDK - Error: The authorization with Token failed

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using a PHP server to generate token. When I initialize the chat client with the token generated, I am getting this error.

> POST https://ems.us1.twilio.com/v1/token 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> {"message":"The authorization with Token
>   failed","code":2016,"user_error":false,"params":{"description":"Could
>   not authenticate fpa token"}}
>
> EMS E: Error: The authorization with Token failed

Javascript (v2.1) initilization code:

```
    Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token).then(client => {
        chatClient = client;
        chatClient.getChannelByUniqueName(channelName)
        .then(function(chosenChannel) {
            myChannel=chosenChannel;
```

PHP Server code:

```
    $token = new AccessToken( $accountid, $apikey, $apisecret 3600, 
    $identity);


    $chatGrant = new ChatGrant();
    $chatGrant->setServiceSid($configs[1]);
    $chatGrant->setEndpointId($endpointId);

    $token->addGrant($chatGrant);

    return $token->toJWT();
```

Any help?

Comment: I checked the token with jwt.io. The keys and ids are correct in the token.

Comment: In one of the solution, it was mentioned to remove the sendEndpointId in token generation. I tried that also. Still it gives the same error.

Comment: Hi @arun-kumar are you able to solve this error?  I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

left colon in  $token = new AccessToken( $accountid, $apikey, $apisecret ##HERE## 3600, 
    $identity);

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon in between the BOLD text below.

> $token = new AccessToken( $accountid, $apikey, **$apisecret  3600**, $identity);